# How to setup Spring Batch with DbUnit?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-test-dbunit

I'm trying to test spring batch using dbunit but when batch runs HibernateCursorItemReader it doesn't see temporary created objects in the db. But if I create entities using HibernateDaoSupport everything is fine and I can work with test data. Does anybody know how to force batch see my test entities?

My test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringEasyMockRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:/integration-test-context.xml"})
@DbUnitConfiguration(
    databaseConnection = {"dbUnitDatabaseConnection"}
)
public abstract class BaseIT implements ApplicationContextAware {
...
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringEasyMockRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/sopl-test-context.xml")
@DatabaseSetup(value = "classpath:data/SoplTestDataIT.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
@Slf4j
public class SoplOrderTestIT extends BaseIT {
...
}
```

And configs integration-test-context.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${hibernate.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${hibernate.connection.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${hibernate.connection.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${c3p0.initialPoolSize:1}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize:0}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize:200}"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime:120}"/>
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="${c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection:100}"/>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${c3p0.checkoutTimeout:30000}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod:3600}"/>
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout:7200}"/>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces"
                  value="${c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces:true}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="namingStrategy">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocations" value="classpath:/hibernate/*-hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props merge="true">
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"/>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- transaction manager for hibernate -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" primary="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- spring-test-dbunit configuration: -->
    <bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
        <property name="qualifiedTableNames" value="true"/>
        <property name="metadataHandler">
            <bean class="org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlMetadataHandler"/>
        </property>
        <property name="datatypeFactory">
            <bean class="org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlDataTypeFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConnection"
          class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
...
```

Comment: Please share your test setup to be able to help you.

Comment: I have added test setup

Comment: Make sure the job is started after db unit has populated the test db and that Spring Batch is configured to use the hibernate transaction manager.